# Setting cookie header in Apache Nutch

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I want to crawl a specific site which uses cookies for authentication. I want to set cookie and user-agent information in every GET request that Apache Nutch makes for crawling the site.

How do I specify the cookie information in the config or is there the need for writing a custom plugin for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there is not way of *manually* specifying a cookie/header for Nutch to send when fetching the URLs. The plugin `protocol-httpclient` have some support for form based authentications, take a look at the `httpclient-auth.xml` file. I don't think this would be too hard to implement, and we always welcome contributions.